# Input operator overloading not working properly // segmentation fault after input from user

Tags: c++, class, input, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I have this class and I'm trying to overload the input operator but i can't get it to work.
Ex2 outputs exactly what it is supposed to output but ex13 give me segmentation fault after entering 2 values.
I'm not allowed to change the type of variables from "private:" access specifier

As input I need to write this(or similar):

```
14
Dell
150
```

These inputs are for(translation from romanian to english):

```
serial number  // serial number
producator  //manufacture
nrPaginiPrintate // number of printed pages

Imprimanta = Printer
```

And here is the code:

````
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Imprimanta
{
private:
    const int serialNumber;
    char* producator;
    int nrPaginiPrintate;
    static string tipImprimanta;
public:
    Imprimanta() :serialNumber(1)
    {
        this->producator = (char*)"";
        this->nrPaginiPrintate = 0;
    }

    Imprimanta(int serialNumber,  const char* producator, int nrPaginiPrintate) :serialNumber(serialNumber)
    {
        string* str = new string();
        *str = producator;
        this->producator = (char*)(str->c_str());
        this->nrPaginiPrintate = nrPaginiPrintate;
    }

    ~Imprimanta(){}

    Imprimanta(const Imprimanta& i) :serialNumber(i.serialNumber) {
        string* str = new string();
        *str = i.producator;
        this->producator = (char*)(str->c_str());
        this->nrPaginiPrintate = i.nrPaginiPrintate;
        this->tipImprimanta = i.tipImprimanta;
    }

    Imprimanta operator=(Imprimanta i)  {
        string* str = new string();
        *str = i.producator;
        this->producator = (char*)(str->c_str());
        this->nrPaginiPrintate = i.nrPaginiPrintate;
        this->tipImprimanta = i.tipImprimanta;
        int* ptr;
        ptr = (int*)(&serialNumber);
        *ptr = i.serialNumber;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator<(Imprimanta t)
    {
        if (nrPaginiPrintate < t.nrPaginiPrintate) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    int get_nrPaginiPrintate() {
        return nrPaginiPrintate;
    }
    void set_nrPaginiPrintate(int pagini_print) {
        this->nrPaginiPrintate = pagini_print;
    }

    static string getTipImprimanta()
    {
        return tipImprimanta;
    }

    static void setTipImprimanta(string tipImprimanta_a)
    {
        tipImprimanta = tipImprimanta_a;
    }

    int get_serialNumber() {
        return serialNumber;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Imprimanta& e);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& in, Imprimanta& e);
};
string Imprimanta::tipImprimanta = "Cerneala";

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Imprimanta& e)
{
    out << "Serial Number: " << e.serialNumber << '\n';
    out << "Producator: " << e.producator << '\n';
    out << "Numar pagini printate: " << e.nrPaginiPrintate << '\n';
    return out;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& in, Imprimanta& e)
{
    int* ptr;
    ptr = (int*)(&e.serialNumber);
    in >> *ptr;
    in >> e.producator;
    in >> e.nrPaginiPrintate;
    return in;
}

int main()
{


    //2
    cout << "-----------------------EX_2-----------------------";
    cout << '\n';
    Imprimanta i2(2, "Canon", 160);
    cout << i2;
    cout << '\n';

    //13
    cout << "-----------------------EX_13-----------------------";
    cout << '\n';
    Imprimanta i11;
    cin >> i11;
    cout << i11;
    cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: The code in the quesiton reads like it was written to demonstrate how broken code can be while it still compiles. If the class definition was given to OP with the request to add an `operator<<`, there is no way to solve the exercise in any meaningful way but to throw away the code and start from scratch. Anyhow, this is adressing the issue in the `operator<<` only and ignores the uncountable other issues...

You probably added this to silence an error due to modifying a `const`:

```
int* ptr;
ptr = (int*)(&e.serialNumber);
in >> *ptr;
```

However, all you achieved is to silence the error. The issue is still present. Actually thats what c-style casts do most of the time: They hide a problem without fixing it. You shall not modify an object that is `const`. If you do, you invoke undefined behavior.

If you want `serialNumber` to be not modifiable, make it `private` and provide no mutator methods. Actually thats already the case, so you can simply remove the `const` and read the value "normal":

```
in >> e.serialNumber;
```

Comment: actually. i would have just made serialNumber a simple int(not const), and producator be string not char* but the teacher that gave this told us that we cannot change the type of variables or their access. something like take this and just solve the exercices. if i modify them i get 0 points for my homework

Comment: @SergiuLuce you must mention such constraints in the question. Please make clear what you can change and what you cannot change.

Comment: sorry. I forgot to mention this. I'll be more carefull next time

Comment: @SerguiLuce why next time? If you cannot apply this fix then this answer does not answer your question and you should clarify the question

Comment: @SergiuLuca its not clear to me what "//I'M NOT ALLOWED TO CHANGE ANY VARIABLE TYPE OR ACCESS FOR IT" means exactly (and why the shouting?!?). `ptr = (int*)(&e.serialNumber);` is accesing a variable and if you cannot change that, you are out of luck. Please make clear what parts of the code are given to you and you cannot change

Comment: Sry, I think now its ok. I'm not allowed to change the type of variables from "private:" access specifier

Comment: // 12. Modify the console writing operator to display information about the Printer
// you can use friend or getter functions
// the display will be of the form:
// Serial number: serialNumber
// Manufacture: Producator
// Number of printed pages: nrPaginiPrintate

// 13. Modify the console read operator to read information about the printer
// the following information will be read in order (each on a new line)
//Producator
// nrPaginiPrintate
// you can use setter or friend functions
// the operator must be able to read strings containing spaces

Comment: @SeriuLuca the class is broken, the same issue as in `operator<<` is present in `operator=`. If thats the class definition you got from your teacher you should complain to them, change the course and never listen to the teacher again

Comment: @SergiuLuca or did you write the `operator=` ? It should not return an object but a reference, but thats the lesser problem.

Comment: That's it. I'll talk to the teacher. Thank you for your time and sorry for the incomplete question.

Comment: @SergiuLuca there are more issues. The class definition almost reads like it was meant to demonstrate bad practice and how to write code that compiles while it is heavily broken

Comment: @SergiuLuca the sad thing is that the code was already broken 10 years ago :/. I cannot help you much remotely, and honestly I have a hard time to believe it, but if the class definition is really provided by your teacher and you are not allowed to change it you might consider to bring this to a higher level, because this is really a clear demonstration of incompetence.

Comment: @SergiuLuca and I am not exaggeration. Every time I look at the code again I find something new that makes me shudder in fear